# Reading data from socket

Tags: php, regex, sockets

I want my code to return:

- **ISP: EdgeCast Networks**
- **Country: United States**

but using this code, I can only get one line, and not all them.
How can I get this information in different lines?

```
$ip="/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=93.184.216.119";
$ISP='/<th>ISP:<\/th><td>(.+)<\/td>/';
$country="/<th>Country:<\/th><td>\s(.+)*$/";    
$fp = fsockopen("www.ip-tracker.org", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} 
else {
    $out = "GET $ip HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.ip-tracker.org\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        if (preg_match($ISP,fgets($fp,128),$matches)) {
            echo "ISP: ".$matches[1]. "<br>";
        }
        if (preg_match($country,fgets($fp,128),$matches)) {
          echo "Country: ".$matches[1]. "<br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the output you are currently getting?

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal example. I guess the whole socket issue has nothing to do with the real problem, has it?

Comment: i dont know how to put it in minimal example, it only gets one line on output, not both lines

Comment: if it returns this: `ISP: EdgeCast Networks` why do you have this :`<th>ISP:<\/th><td>(.+)<\/td>`. It doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @user7874: You're attempting to parse HTML. Use a DOM parser instead of a regex. (Googling for "php domdocument examples" should get you started)

Comment: @Tuga the entire page returns a lot of things, i need regex to catch that information
the fact is, i want to catch a lot of information from that page, but using while it can only get one information and not all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.ip-tracker.org/locator/ip-lookup.php?ip=93.184.216.119");

preg_match_all('%Country:</th><td> (.*?) &nbsp;.*?<th>ISP:</th><td>(.*?)</td>%sm', $html, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$country = $result[1][0];
$isp = $result[2][0];

echo $country; // United States
echo $isp; // EdgeCast Networks
?>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, thats exactly what i was looking for, didnt know i could use file_get_contents and preg_match_all in this case

Comment: what does the %sm means?

Comment: `s` -> dot matches newline; `m` -> ^ and $ match at line breaks